# How to install a private repo in Docker (compose) on Windows with ssh config file

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, ssh

I am trying to get my SSH credentials/socket safely used when building a Docker without exposing anything on Windows 11.

The best way nowadays to install a private repo inside a Docker seems to be using the ssh socket.
Specifying like so in my `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.production.yaml` - some irrelevant details are omitted:

```
# Build image
FROM python:3.10.8-slim-bullseye AS builder

RUN mkdir -p /home/user/proj
WORKDIR /home/user/proj

# Copy repo.
COPY . .

RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y \
    && apt install curl openssh-client git -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh \
    && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

# Installation.
# Disable virtual env creation as it requires an extra package and it's not needed in the Container.
RUN --mount=type=ssh curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | POETRY_HOME=/opt/poetry python - \
    && export PATH="/opt/poetry/bin:$PATH" \
    && poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install --with prod \
    && poetry export -f requirements.txt >> requirements.txt --with prod
```

```
celery:
    image: proj
    container_name: worker
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
      ssh:
        - default
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      SSH_AUTH_SOCK: $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
    volumes:
      - $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:$SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

First problem, on my pc `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` seems not to be set, but I found on Windows it should be `\\.\pipe\openssh-ssh-agent` which is set in the `.env` file.

I prefer to use a local `.ssh` folder in the root of the repository with a `config` file there to submit into version control (only the config file naturally). However, it also lives under `C:/Users/Name/.ssh` for now to enable local cloning/installation.

```
Host github.com-otherproj
    Hostname github.com
    IdentityFile=~/.ssh/otherproj_ed25519
```

This `otherproj` is a private repository accessible to me. I can clone (and install) it using my own SSH credentials locally using `git clone git@github.com-otherproj:org/otherproj.git`.

When bringing up the docker compose file, it throws

```
HangupException

ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com-otherproj: Name or service not known
```

I tried to get all of the setup working in VSCode and in PowerShell, but both fail. Also read a lot of confusing posts about all this on GitHub issues and SO, but it's really hard to find a fix. Especially since the recommended way to do this has changed relatively recently.